# bidirectional socket (non-blocking) with c

Tags: c, sockets, nonblocking

i try to do a kind-of chat over TCP sockets. The server side is implemented in php and (should) work fine.

No i've encountered a problem on the client side (implemented in c [c99]):

i'd like to listen (read) for "new bytes" from the server and i also would like to send (write) "some bytes" to the server whenever the user did enter new data.

Now the question:
-> how do i listen for incoming traffic (read) and still be able to call every 1 seconds a callback where i can check for new bytes to send to the server?
I know that i have to use select (system call) but i do not have a idea how to handle the timeout etc. select is also blocking for a certain time.

Thanks for any example.

Comment: Have you considered using threads?

Comment: Threads will solve the problem in a bad way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function called `select` that can be used for this. It can check if there is new input on a socket to read, and it has a timeout so it can be used for your timer as well.

It exists on one form or other on all major operating systems. Just do a Google search for `socket select <your operating system> example` and you will get a boat-load of results.

---

The last argument to `select` is used for the timeout. It's a pointer to a `struct timeval`, a structure which contains fields to set the timeout.

If this pointer is passed as `NULL` then there is no timeout, and `select` can block indefinitely.

To set a timeout, you need to set the `tv_sec` field of the `timeval` structure to the number of seconds, and the `tv_usec` field to the number of microseconds (must be less than one million). You can have a timeout of zero, i.e. just a quick poll, by setting these fields to zero.

If `select` returns zero, then there was a timeout.

Example, with a 1.5 second timeout:

```
for (;;)
{
    fd_set readset;
    int maxfd;

    /* Initialize and set `readset` and `maxfd` */

    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec  = 1;
    tv.tv_usec = 500000;

    int res = select(maxfd + 1, &readset, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    if (res == -1)
        perror("select");  /* Error */
    else if (res == 0)
    {
        /* Timeout, do something */
    }
    else
    {
        /* A socket in `readset` is readable */
    }
}
```

If `select` returns *before* the timeout, the `timeval` structure is modified to contain the time remaining of the timeout.

Comment: Thanks. I know that i have to use select. But how do i set the timeout? select also blocks.... any ideas examples? i could not find a example for c by a google search.

Comment: you also found a broken link!

Comment: @JonasSchnelli As the link you found no longer works, I've updated my answer to include some more text, and an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [select](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28Unix%29) system call, with the `timeout` parameter set as needed.
[Beej's guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#select) is still a good source with plenty of example code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the select [system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28Unix%29) call. You could also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063366/read-and-write-to-same-socket-tcp-using-select) useful.